# Perl compound condition for while?

Tags: perl

I have something like

```
my $ token = readToken();
while (length($token) > 0) {
  # do stuff with $token
  $token = readToken();
}
```

I can't help feeling I have missed a construction where I don't have two calls
to `readtoken`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my $token; 
while (($token = readToken()) && (length($token) > 0)) {
  # do stuff with $token
}
```

Comment: @harmic have changed my answer

Comment: I'm glad you posted that because that is what I initially tried. With Perl 5.8.0, I get `Global symbol "$token" requires explicit package name at test line 11. Execution of test aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick have changed my answer. Please try again.

Comment: You can also avoid that precedence problem by using `and` instead of `&&`.

Comment: Note that this doesn't do what you imagine, because if `readToken` returns a null string then it will evaluate to *false* and the length will never get checked. In other words, the length of `$token` is only tested when it is non-zero, so the test always succeeds! It does what you want, but is really equivalent to just `while ( $token = readToken() ) { ... }`

Comment: @Borodin but makes `length(null)` sence?

Comment: @Jens: By *null string* I mean a string with length zero, written as `""`

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work

```
while ( length( my $token = readToken() ) > 0 ) {
  # do stuff with token
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your own answer is pretty good. Or you can write an infinite loop and construct the `while` logic by hand:

```
while () {
  my $token = readToken();
  last if length($token) == 0;
  # do stuff with $token
}
```

Comment: [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) :)

Answer (score -1):

Your original loop should be:

```
my $token = readToken();
while (length($token) > 0) {
  # do stuff with $token
}continue{
  $token = readToken();
}
```

The difference is that anything in the `continue` clause will be executed when `next` is called. To skip the `continue` but loop again, use `redo`.

See:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html